# Discord.py - Sending a message within a synchronous function

Tags: python, flask, asynchronous, discord.py

I am currently working on a Python program using Flask and Discord.py. The program will take parameters from an HTTP GET Request, and then the bot will send them in a message to a specific channel in my Discord server. However, I cannot figure out how to send a message every time a new GET Request is sent since it uses an asynchronous function. My current code is

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from flask import Flask, request
from threading import Thread

bot = Bot("!")
messageToSend = ""
recievedMessage = ""

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return messageToSend

@app.route('/login',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
   global recievedMessage
   if request.method == 'GET':
      user = request.args.get('nm')
      message = request.args.get('msg')
      recievedMessage = f"[{user}]: {message}"
      print(recievedMessage)
      return user

def run ():
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)

def keep_alive():
    t = Thread(target=run)
    t.start()

@bot.command()
async def send():
  message = send_message()
  channel = bot.get_channel(852280470384410654)
  await channel.send(message)

keep_alive()
bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

I have tried other methods, such as using Asyncio, but none of them have been able to work. Is it possible to do what I am attempting?

Comment: You should use this https://pypi.org/project/discord-ext-ipc/